# JavaScript Undefined with jQuery deferred

Tags: jquery, ajax, undefined, jquery-deferred

I am trying to write an AJAX request using the jQuery `.Deferred/.promise`. The function gets hit when the page loads and then nothing happens and I can't access my `issueData` variable. When I run the function it is undefined, but my AJAX call return JSON objects. I'm trying to figure out if the issue is in how I setup the `issueData` `.deferred()` and `.promise()`

```
function getIssues(issueData) {
    var issueData = new jQuery.Deferred();
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:49650/Issues.svc/GetIssues',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            issueData = data;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Call not resolved')
        }
    });
    return issueData.promise();    
}
```

Comment: After `return $.ajax`, nothing is executed in your function, so you never get to `return issueData.promise();`

Comment: It appears as though you're attempting to use asynchronous programming, but then reverting back to doing stuff like `issueData = data` which doesn't help you get that data.

Comment: Kevin, I am attempting too, but I haven't been successful in my attempts while learning. Would you mind giving a correct example or resource? The answer given still returns undefined so I imagine I have structured something incorrectly.

Comment: @Alexander The most recent edit of rodrigovz's answer is structured properly, however you most likely don't even need the success and error callbacks. You could probably just do this: http://pastebin.com/dyG048Pa

Comment: @KevinB works perfectly thanks. Do you want to submit an answer for me to mark correct? Thanks.

Comment: @Alexander Rocket's answer covers that pastebin pretty well, the first snippet is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `jQuery.Deferred()` here, `$.ajax` handles this for you.  You just need to `return $.ajax({})`.  Also, since AJAX is *asynchronous*, your `issueData = data;` won't do anything useful.

You need to use callbacks to get the returned data.

You can do this:

```
function getIssues() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:49650/Issues.svc/GetIssues',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function () {
            alert('Call not resolved')
        }
    }); 
}

getIssues().done(function(data){
    // use the returned JSON here
});
```

Or, you can use the `success` function:

```
function getIssues() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:49650/Issues.svc/GetIssues',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            // use the returned JSON here
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Call not resolved')
        }
    }); 
}

getIssues();
```

Answer (score 3):

A $.resolve() statement is missing and you have two 'return' statement, the second 'return' is never reached.

A solution is this:

```
 function getIssues(issueData) {
   var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
   $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:49650/Issues.svc/GetIssues',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var receivedData = data;
        ....    
        deferred.resolve();
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Call not resolved')
    }
   });
   return deferred.promise();    
 }
```

Comment: The resolve doesn't really do anything since he doesn't return issueData from getIssues.